# Table of distances with python and google maps api

Tags: python, csv, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API to check the distance between two points, for that, I have two files worker.csv  and job.csv.

The goal is to know the distance of the worker for each job.

If there are 3 workes and 2 jobs, the expected result was to be:

```
worker1, job1
worker1, job2
worker2, job1
worker2, job2
worker3, job1
worker3, job2
```

But the code is returning only the first item of job:

```
worker1, job1
worker1, job2
```

I believe the error is in the **for**

```
import googlemaps
import csv

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='TOKEN')

column_work = 0
column_job = 0

geo_worker = open('files/work.csv', 'r')
geo_job = open('files/job.csv', 'r')
out = open('files/output.csv', 'w', newline='')

try:
    open_work = csv.reader(geo_worker)
    open_job = csv.reader(geo_job)
    write = csv.writer(out)
    for row in list(open_job)[1:]:
        location_job = row[column_job]
        for row in list(open_work)[1:]:
            location_work = row[column_work]
            distance = gmaps.distance_matrix(location_work, location_job)
            print(distance)

finally:
    geo_worker.close()
    geo_job.close()
    out.close()
```

I would also like to get the result in table format, in the output.csv file in the following template:

```
worker1, distance(1,1), distance(1,2)
worker2, distance(2,1), distance(2,2)
worker3, distance(3,1), distance(1,2)
```

Comment: Add a sample of the source csv files, so we can check/run your assumptions and algorithm with the same dataset.

Comment: Plus, in both loops for itteracting the data you are using the same variable name  - `row`, that is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very common mistake when handling files as generators, which is essentially what you are doing, is to not consider that they get exhausted, once read. That means, the open_work data is only available for the first job.

The most common solution to the problem is to first read the file content into a data structure and then re-use that in order to have the data available. Thus, you have to introduce an extra read loop.

Further, to re-arrange the output, you will need to store the full solution in a data structure, and then re-arrange. Thus you need one loop for building the structure and one loop for printing. Thus, you need the total of three loops to solve this. This could be solved as:

```
import googlemaps
import csv

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='TOKEN')

column_work = 0
column_job = 0

worker_pos = {}
worker_distance = {}

with open('files/work.csv', 'r') as geo_worker:
    open_work = csv.reader(geo_worker)
    open_work.next() # Your solution seems to drop the first line?
    for row_num, row in enumerate(open_work):
        worker_pos[row_num] = row[column_work]

with open('files/job.csv', 'r') as geo_job:
    open_job = csv.reader(geo_job)
    open_job.next() # Your solution seems to drop the first line?
    for row in open_job:
        location_job = row[column_job]
        for worker in worker_pos:
            if not worker_distance.has_key(worker)
                worker_distance[worker] = [] # list of distances to work
            distance = gmaps.distance_matrix(worker_pos[worker], location_job)
            worker_distance[worker].append(distance)

with open('files/output.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    write = csv.writer(out)
    sorted_keys = sorted(worker_distance.keys())
    for entry in sorted_keys:
        output_row = "worker{}".format(entry)
        for dist in worker_distance[entry]:
            output_row += ", {}".format(dist)
        write.writerow(formatted_output)    
        #print(formatted_output)
```

As I do not know the structure of your csv files, I am not totally sure that this solution fulfills your needs, but at least it should put you on the right path.